# Conditionally format cells of pandas to_html

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like following

```
print(df_t)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   foo  bar
a    1    2
b    9    7
```

This generates following html

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th></th>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>b</th>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to bold cell values that are larger in row
For example
In the first row, want to "bolden" value 2, and in the second row bolden value 9.

Comment: is `'a' 'b'` index?

Comment: yeah.. they are indices.

Answer (score 2):

Use [styles](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Building-styles) and generate html by [`Styler.render`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render.html):

```
def highlight_max(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series bolder.
    '''
    is_max = s == s.max()
    return ['font-weight: bolder' if v else '' for v in is_max]

html = df.style.apply(highlight_max, axis=1).render()

print (html)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `jinja2`

```py
from jinja2 import Template #pip install Jinja2

s = """<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th></th>
      {% for cloumn in df.columns %}
      <th>{{cloumn}}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for index, row in df.iterrows() %}
    <tr>
      <th>{{index}}</th>
      {% for val in row.values %}
        {% if val == row.values.max() %}
            <td><strong>{{val}}<strong></td>
        {% else -%}
            <td>{{val}}</td>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>"""

output_html = Template(s).render({'df': df})

print(output_html)
```

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th></th>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
        <td>1</td>
            <td><strong>2<strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>b</th>
            <td><strong>9<strong></td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```